# Proguard removes com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider

Tags: java, android, kotlin, proguard

In my app I send emails to some specific address, it all works fine, but when it comes to obfuscation, shrinking, etc with ProGuard it fails

I've tried adding some ProGuard rules, which didn't work

That's my ProGuard

```
-keepclassmembernames class com.sun.mail.imap
```

```
2019-08-08 14:29:26.811 11724-12675/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
    Process: com.redegrow.besttaxi, PID: 11724
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        ...
     Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: e.b.r: Provider com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider not found
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:233)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:183)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:373)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:416)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:494)
     ...
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider
     ...
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.redegrow.besttaxi-_Kl-yVNRgbmmwzLXuKKmWQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.redegrow.besttaxi-_Kl-yVNRgbmmwzLXuKKmWQ==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
       ...
```

Comment: do not use proguard or minify...make app bundles and let the playstore sign the app. Optimization will be done by them
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found the solution.
It's not great, but at least it works

```
-keep class com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPProvider
-keep class com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLProvider
-keep class com.sun.mail.smtp.** {*;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `keepclassmembernames` for a class tells ProGuard not to obfuscate the class members, but does not have an effect on the class itself. So ProGuard does its job and changes the class name.

So if you want to prevent ProGuard from obfuscating the class name you should use `keepnames` instead.

To prevent both the obfuscation and shrinking (which is removing in case of not being used), you should use `keepclassmembers` if you want to target only the class members and `keep` to target the class itself and its members.